# Windings for Linear Generator

Tags: generator

I have built a small, simple linear generator. It works, but I'm sure it could be more efficient because I didn't know how many windings of magnet wire to use.  I know there is a formula I could use to determine how many windings but have been unable to find it. Can someone provide me the formula or where I can find it?

Now for more details of the project in case that somehow helps. I have a cylinder about 2.5 cm long and about .4 cm inner diameter. I have a cylindrical neodymium magnet that just fits inside and is about .2 in height. Of course, when I hold my fingers at the ends and shake back and forth I get a small current. I would like to be able to light an LED (hopefully a super bright). I realize it will strobe on and off - which is exactly what I want. I haven't yet used it with an LED, but did connect it up to a multitester to see that I was generating a current. Perhaps I will need to upsize the magnet/change the cylinder size (diameter or length). I'm hoping I will not need to change things too much as I have space limitations. But I could change things a bit if needed. If anyone has thoughts, I would be happy to hear them, although the winding issue is more what I'm hoping to have answered.

Thanks

Comment: Outer diameter of cylinder and cylinder material?

Comment: .5 outer diameter. Plastic material.